# How to update availability set by user?

Tags: django

I have a model with two users Student and Consultant.
Consultant is able to set up his availability like this:

```
from django.db import models
from userregistration.models import UserProfile


class Setup_Availability(models.Model):
    consultant = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='consultant_availability')
    start_date = models.DateField()  # The date when availability starts
    monday_start_time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    monday_end_time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    tuesday_start_time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    tuesday_end_time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    wednesday_start_time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    wednesday_end_time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    thursday_start_time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    thursday_end_time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    friday_start_time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    friday_end_time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    saturday_start_time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    saturday_end_time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    sunday_start_time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    sunday_end_time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Availability for {self.consultant.user.username} starting on {self.start_date}"
```

And  Student will be able to book appointment through:

```
class Appointment(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='student_appointments')
    consultant = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='consultant_appointments')
    appointment_datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    appointment_start_time = models.TimeField()
    appointment_end_time = models.TimeField()
    is_available = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.student.user.username} - {self.consultant.user.username} - {self.appointment_datetime}"
```

```
def book_appointment(request):
    day_of_week_name = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday']
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AppointmentBookingForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            consultant = form.cleaned_data['consultant']
            date = form.cleaned_data['date']
            appointment_start_time = form.cleaned_data['appointment_start_time']
            appointment_end_time = form.cleaned_data['appointment_end_time']

            # Check if the selected time slot is available
            availability = Setup_Availability.objects.get(consultant=consultant)
            day_of_week = date.weekday()
            available_start_time = getattr(availability, f'{day_of_week_name[day_of_week]}_start_time')
            available_end_time = getattr(availability, f'{day_of_week_name[day_of_week]}_end_time')

            selected_start_time = datetime.combine(date, appointment_start_time)
            selected_end_time = datetime.combine(date, appointment_end_time)

            if (available_start_time <= selected_start_time.time() < available_end_time and
                    available_start_time < selected_end_time.time() <= available_end_time):
                student_email = request.user.email
                consultant_email = consultant.user.email
                print(student_email)
                # The selected time slot is available, so create the appointment
                appointment = Appointment(
                    student=request.user.userprofile,
                    consultant=consultant,
                    appointment_datetime=selected_start_time,
                    appointment_start_time=selected_start_time,
                    appointment_end_time=selected_end_time,
                )
                appointment.save()

                # Set the availability slot as unavailable
                setattr(availability, f'{day_of_week_name[day_of_week]}_start_time', selected_end_time.time())
                availability.save()

                return redirect('appointment_success')
    else:
        form = AppointmentBookingForm()

    return render(request, 'book_appointment/book_appointment.html', {'form': form})
```

What I need to do is to be able to update the availability set up by consultant so that time booked by student becomes unavailable and remaining times set up by consultant becomes available. I donot know if I am doing this wrong the whole way or if it is even possible. Any workoaround or alternative way will be really appreciated